# Visaulize several .vtk files together in Paraview

Tags: matlab, paraview, visualize

I am running some simulations on Matlab and then passing them to Paraview using .vtk files. I would like to see all three .vtk files together in Paraview screen but it seems like I can visualise them only one by one, not together.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you just load each file (File->Open) one at a time and then view them all together?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to visualize several .vtk files together in Paraview.

Just hit "Ctrl+O" and select the files you want to visualize.

After that you have to hit apply in any of the loaded files in order to update the pipeline.

Watch out for naming!

If you name your files like:

file1.vtk

file2.vtk

file3.vtk

They will be loaded as a TimeSeries and visualized as an animation. One at a timestep.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score -1):

With ParaView 5.3, you can apply the **Group TimeSteps** filter, to group all the timesteps into a single multiblock dataset with each timestep added as a separate block.